# JBoss EAP 6.3 - SSO and Sticky Sessions not working

Tags: apache-2.2, jboss, single-sign-on, sticky-sessions

We have a cluster with 2 nodes (JBoss EAP 6.3 with Single Sign On enabled), node 1 and node 2 in different servers. On top of that we have an Apache2 and are using mod_cluster for load balancing and sticky sessions. We also have our web apps with distributable tag ().

The thing is that the sticky session seems to work on the same web app, but when we navigate to another web app it brakes stickness.

Example: User goes to web app A, node 1 gets the request. When the user navigates to web app B, node 2 gets the request. With sticky sessions turned on and SSO enabled, shouldnt the user get the same node (node 1) ? In this scenario the node 1 should get always the requests of the user, cause is the one that got the first request.

Could you guys point us to the right direction ?
Thanks, Regards.

Comment: Take a look in https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/html/Security_Guide/chap-Single_Sign_On_SSO.html and check your configuration

Comment: Ran into a similar situation with ours. We ended up writing into the session the nodename of the original worker so that we can keep directing that session to that node. The unfortunate part is that any sessions relaying on that node will all break should that node go down.

Comment: How and What did you guys write ? What is the format that apache uses to identify the node ?